# Remove query string from url using rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Im trying to rewrite url in htaccess file.
Original url:

`www.mywebsite.com/flash/module.swf?xmlpath=http%3a%2f%2f0.0.0.0%3a8000%2fconfig.xml`

I want to remove query string from this url. This condition should applied only for .xml extension.

Output URL should be

`www.mywebsite.com/flash/module.swf`

Answer (score 0):

You can match a query string with a `RewriteCond` and `%{QUERY_STRING}`. If the second argument of a `RewriteRule` contains a query string, it will overwrite the existing query string. Clearing the query string is as easy as appending a `?` to your url ;-) Alternativelly, you can use the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.xml$
RewriteRule ^flash/module\.swf$ flash/module.swf? [L]
```

Change the flags (`[L]`) to `[R,L]` or `[R=301,L]` if you want this to be an external redirect instead.